# Remove related row from pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

| id | relatedId | coordinate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 125 | 55 |
| 125 | 123 | 45 |
| 128 | 130 | 60 |
| 132 | 135 | 50 |
| 130 | 128 | 40 |
| 135 | 132 | 50 |

So I have 6 rows in this dataframe, but I would like to get rid of the related rows resulting in 3 rows. The coordinate column equals 100 between the two related rows, and I would like to keep the one with the lowest value (so the one less than 50. If both are 50, simply one of them). The resulting dataframe would thus be:

| id | relatedId | coordinate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | 123 | 45 |
| 132 | 135 | 50 |
| 130 | 128 | 40 |

Hopefully someone has a good solution for this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the values and get the first value per group using a `frozenset` of the 2 ids as grouper:

```
(df
 .sort_values(by='coordinate')
 .groupby(df[['id', 'relatedId']].agg(frozenset, axis=1), as_index=False)
 .first()
)
```

output:

```
    id  relatedId  coordinate
0  130        128          40
1  125        123          45
2  132        135          50
```

Alternatively, to keep the original order, and original indices, use `idxmin` per group:

```
group = df[['id', 'relatedId']].agg(frozenset, axis=1)
idx = df['coordinate'].groupby(group).idxmin()
df.loc[sorted(idx)]
```

output:

```
    id  relatedId  coordinate
1  125        123          45
3  132        135          50
4  130        128          40
```